# Does AE have a different mentality when it comes to voting?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I recently started joining other SE sites, and I noticed that getting votes on answers, is much easier and faster than here. It seems like a good answer will always get upvotes.

I do understand that this site might not have as many active members as other sites do, but good answer should still get some votes, and the only reason that I can think of as to why people don't vote, is because they simply don't read answers.

My criteria for upvoting is, if the answer is written well, and falls into one of the following, it will automatically get my upvote:

- I know the answer is correct
- answer was accepted by OP and being that it worked, I can safely assume that it's correct
- answer is backed by reliable sources, and therefore, is most probably correct.

I try my best to upvote the answers that fall into one of the three categories, while I see that that's not done by others. Is there a reason that I'm missing?

So I'd like to hear from others, in what cases would you vote, and in what case would you avoid voting even though the answer falls into the above categories?

Hopefully this will help influence the way I, and other, answer questions.

Comment: To my experience, "voting mentality" isn't much different on SoftwareRecs either.

Comment: Not gonna write a full answer for this - but personally I usually don't read answers unless it's to a question I'm already interested in.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that *questions* here don't get many votes, up or down, which I find a pain

Comment: ...but not as annoying as the lack of *answers* or even *comments* to questions. Maybe it's because there's too much competition with xda and android central?

Comment: I guess it all boils down to the amount of community members, but I do see cases where it's obvious that someone read the post, and the post is obviously true, but they don't upvote, for that, I guess I'll never know the reason

Comment: Personally, as @AndyYan does, I don't read answers which don't interest me personally. If a question is of interest and has multiple answers, I only upvote either the one I believe to be the best, or the one I applied successfully.